# exceptional <td> with no hover

Tags: css

I have a table with many `<td>`s inside of it, and with a specific style stored in a CSS file and they have a hover style, but I want to not apply the hover for one specific `<td>`.

So I tried to give it an ID and make the hover look like the background and it didn't work!  That `<td>` has the same hover as others

This is my CSS:

```
#gradient-style tbody td:hover
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
}

td#exception:hover
{
    padding: 0px;
    background: #e8edff;
}
```

My exceptional `<td>` doesn't get its exceptional hover; it gets the same as others.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your selector isn't [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) enough.

The first selector has one more id selector in it than the second selector, so it wins the cascade.

Use:

```
#gradient-style tbody td#exception:hover
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the css formatting is correct

Try

```
td#exception:hover
{
    padding: 0px !important;
    background: #e8edff !important;
}
```

Shouldn't really use it but it works

Comment: "Shouldn't really use it" — Correct. It is a brute force hammer of a solution that only works once (since when you want to override it, it is already important). Use the specificity rules properly instead.